# Spring Boot 3 - Refactoring Projects Error

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 3, and refactored a couple project package names so they all align with com.myproject.foo.
Now, when I try to run them I get this error:

Error: Could not find or load main class com.luv2code.employee.project.EmployeeProjectApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myoldprojectname.employee.project.EmployeeProjectApplication

I'm using Spring STS & Maven as my build tool, changed the Maven Artifact names,but could not find anywhere to change the meta data of the separate projects so they all a-line as one.

What am I missing??

Changing the Artifact id's and renaming the packages.